# Postgres FDW: Is it possible to execute a foreign function in a foreign server after importing the foreign schema?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-fdw

I imported a foreign schema using IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA.
Now I'm able to access all the table content in that schema, but still unable to access any of the functions.

Is it possible to execute a foreign function on the foreign server? With FDW or any other way.

Comment: FDWs only support tables (as of Postgres 14)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Okay got it. Is there any workaround to make this happen?

Comment: It should be possible using [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dblink to accomplish this.  Fortunately, dblink will accept the name of a foreign server in place of the connection string.  Unfortunately, it does still remain a bit ugly as the return types must be specified in the query (among other ugliness):

```
select * from dblink('foreign_server_name', 'select foobar(42)') f(i int);
```